# How to globally set query timeout for ElasticSearch Transport Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, timeout

We are using 1.5.2 version of the java ElasticSearch client.

We want to set the client side timeout for a query to exactly 1s, preferably globally/once.

The 1.5 documentation mentions the

`transport.tcp.connnect_timeout` but that does not actually timeout our queries.

Using

`client.transport.ping_timeout` does not give us the expected behaviour either.

Our cluster is at 1.5.2.